# Ограничение длины метки

Tags: теги, php

Как можно ограничить длину одной метки (тега)?
Например, если пользователь вводит `метка`, то пропускаем ее, а если вводит `оченьоченьдлиннаяметка`, то пишем, что она слишком длинная.

Comment: @GALGANOVIN, валидация длины никак не связана с движком базы данных. Там, конечно, есть ограничение по длине, но вышеописанный вами функционал никогда не бывает связан с БД.

Comment: Нет, мне не нужно, чтобы метки были слишком длинные, так как портит общий вид. Теги добавляются самими пользователями, а как таковой модерации нет, чтобы отслеживать их. Все метки вводятся через запятую в поле, а мне нужно просто ограничить длину одной метки до 8-10 символов. А вот с БД лажанул, простите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

прежде, чем записывать метку в БД, вы посчитайте количество символов в ней, и, в зависимости от того, сколько символов, разрешайте запись в БД или же нет. К примеру strlen использовать можно.